# Traducir consulta SQL a LINQ C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, linq

Espero se encuentren bien. Mi duda corresponde al siguiente estracto de código SQL Server:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(CreatedAt < '2021-11-05', 1, 0)) AS Returning,
SUM(IIF(CreatedAt BETWEEN '2021-11-05' AND '2021-11-11', 1, 0)) AS New 
FROM Customers
WHERE GroupId = 'LS4X2QWRFH'
GO
```

Prácticamente lo que hace es que en base a una fecha de inicio (**2021-11-05**) y fecha de fin (**2021-11-11**) yo selecciono la cantidad de clientes que estan antes de la fecha de inicio y a aquellos que estan entre la fecha de inicio y fin, el resultado son dos campos con valores que me indican cuantos hay para cada caso:

[image: Resultado SQL Server]

Ahora, lo que quiero es realizar lo mismo pero desde LINQ en C#, he realizado algunas pruebas en LinqPad pero solo he logrado realizarlo haciendolo por separado:

```
var customers = Customers.Where(cs => cs.GroupId.Equals(groupId));

var New = await customers.SumAsync(cs => cs.CreatedAt >= startDate && cs.CreatedAt <= endDate ? 1 : 0);
var Returning = await customers.SumAsync(cs => cs.CreatedAt < startDate ? 1 : 0);
```

Si bien obtengo los mismos resultados:
[image: Resultado LINQ]

Por detrás esto esta significando ejecutar dos consultas SQL, contrario a poder realizarlo en una sola desde SQL Server (como se mostró en el código SQL anterior). Adjunto una imagen desde LINQPad con la proyeccion final de la consulta ejecutada, que a su vez tiene sentido porque se hace un SumAsync por separado despues de preparar el IQUeryable():

[image: Linq to SQL]
*Si los campos no tienen relacion es porque yo lo simplifique para hacer la pregunta, pero el objetivo es el mismo.*

He pensado en algo como esto:

```
var customers = await Customers.Where(cs => cs.GroupId.Equals(groupId))
                .Select(cs => new {
                    New = cs.CreatedAt >= startDate && cs.CreatedAt <= endDate ? 1 : 0, 
                    Returning = cs.CreatedAt < startDate ? 1 : 0
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

Siendo razonables esto no funciona porque me devolverá muchas filas donde habran dos columnas (New y Returning) con ceros y unos cada fila, siendo totalmente diferente al resultado esperado.

No puedo realizar un `Sum()` en ese Select porque no trato con una colección ya en ese punto.

He pensado en crear variables locales dentro del `Select()` que acumulen los valores según sea el caso y ya despues asignarlos, tambien en agrupar los campos.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo puedo hacer un equivalente de la consulta de SQL Server en LINQ?

Comment: Has comprobado que efectivamente realiza dos consultas al servidor? Yo no lo tengo nada claro, ya que la primera que haces, `var customers = Customers.Where(cs => cs.GroupId.Equals(groupId));` sí que debería ejecutarse contra el servidor, pero las otras dos se hacen contra el objeto en memoria.

Comment: Si, lo he comprobado, esa linea solo prepara el IQueryable<T>() para luego hacer consultas por separado con SumAsync(), que es hasta este punto donde se ejecutan y como son dos, son dos consultas por separado a la BD. Agregare una captura extra para que se pueda observar.

Comment: Hazle un ToList() entonces, ahí hará la llamada al servidor y luego las otras dos las hace sobre el objeto en memoria

Comment: Si, eso lo hice antes, y despues solo los transforme ya con la lista obtenida, fue lo primero, pero queria intentar traducirla. De momento esta sera la alternativa que probablemente tome, porque no encuentro otra forma. Al final siempre itero sobre cada fila, asi que supongo no tendria porque dar problemas.

Comment: ¡Ah! Ok, Brandon, si es porque quieres traducirla, me parece bien. Pero yo lo haría simple: `var customers = Customers.Where(cs => cs.GroupId.Equals(groupId)).ToList();`, porque posiblemente sea hasta más eficiente.

Comment: Si, tienes razón, de momento es la solución y sin complicarse, no todo tiene que ser tal cual en SQL. Asi lo hare. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo, solo recuerda que cuando traduces una consulta, el resultado final se obtiene por partes al usar LINQ, incluso en tu prueba ya lo tienes, solo debes unirlo y ordenarlo asi:

```
var customers = Customers.Where(cs => cs.GroupId.Equals(groupId))
                         .Select(g => new {
                            News = g.Where(cs => cs.CreatedAt >= startDate && cs.CreatedAt <= endDate).Count(),
                            Returning = g.Where(cs => cs.CreatedAt < startDate).Count();
                         })
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```